# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Excel' not found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-excel

In my controller I have the code as below:

```
Excel::create('Laravel Excel', function($excel) {

        $excel->sheet('Excel sheet', function($sheet) {

            $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');

        });

    })->export('xls');
```

In config/app.php in aliases array i have defined this:

```
'Excel'     => 'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider',
```

I dont know why i cant make it work this library...
Any idea?

Comment: Did you run `composer dump` from `terminal/command prompt` to update the `autoloader`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of `Excel::create` you should use `\Excel::create` or add at the beginning of your file after current namespace `use Excel;` and then you will be able to use `Excel::create`

And the second error is that you used:

```
'Excel'     => 'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider',
```

and you should use:

```
'Excel' => 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel',
```

instead according to the [docs](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel).

Comment: Very strange that it still doesnt work :s Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::create()

Answer (score 6):

After all this you need to check whether or not you have this at the top:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, clearing configuration cache makes it work

`php artisan config:cache`

This should work after all you have followed all the instruction correctly but still getting **"Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Excel' not found in Laravel"** error

Answer (score 3):

In laravel 5.4, First install the composer using following command

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel:~2.1
```

then, add the following in **config/app.php** file providers

```
Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
```

then, add the following in **config/app.php** file aliases

```
'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
```

then, add this in your **controller** file

```
use Excel;
```